# How to fix this Keras ValueErrors for Image classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm trying to perform a binary image classification using keras library but i'm getting a ValueError as Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 2)

```
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape=(64,64,3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
#Pooling_layers
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
#conv_layers
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))
#Max_pooling_layers
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))
#Compile_classifier
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/train',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

classifier.fit_generator(
        train_set,
        steps_per_epoch=9000,
        epochs=25,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=3000)
```

On executing my program, I'm having this error message.

`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 2)`

Comment: I think you should add the `batch_size` argument to `model.compile`. Also, try printing what `train_set` returns and see the shape of the data.

Comment: I tried adding batch_size to model.compile but still it showed an error

Comment: And what about `train_set`? What is the shape of the data coming out of it?

Comment: training set data consist of 66images